# Yet another BrainF*** Interpretter in Haskell

Tags: haskell, interpreter, brainfuck

I wrote a BrainF*** interpretter in Haskell. A general review would be helpful and especially, a suggestion with a better way to deal with the `IO (IO Memory, IO ())` would be helpful.

```
import Data.Either
import Data.List
import Data.Char
import System.Environment
import System.IO

type Program = [Instruction]

data Instruction = Lft
            | Rgt
            | Inc
            | Dec
            | Nop
            | Loop Program
            | Out
            | Inp
            deriving Eq

data Memory = Memory [Int] [Int]

emptyMem :: Memory
emptyMem = Memory [] [0]

parse :: String -> Program
parse xs = go xs []
   where
      go :: String -> [Either Char Instruction] -> Program
      go "" is      = reverse $ rights is
      go ('[':xs) is   = go xs ((Left '['):is)
      go (']':xs) is   = go xs ((Right l):l2)
         where
            (l1, (_:l2)) =  span (/= Left '[') is
            l = Loop $ (rights.reverse) l1
      go ('>':xs) is   = go xs (Right Rgt:is)
      go ('<':xs) is   = go xs (Right Lft:is)
      go ('+':xs) is   = go xs (Right Inc:is)
      go ('-':xs) is   = go xs (Right Dec:is)
      go ('.':xs) is   = go xs (Right Out:is)
      go (',':xs) is   = go xs (Right Inp:is)

runInstruction :: Memory -> Instruction -> IO (IO Memory, IO ())
runInstruction mem Nop = return (return mem, return ())
runInstruction (Memory xs (y:[])) Rgt = return (return (Memory (y:xs) [0]), return ())
runInstruction (Memory xs (y:ys)) Rgt = return (return (Memory (y:xs) ys), return ())
runInstruction (Memory (x:xs) ys) Lft = return (return (Memory xs (x:ys)), return ())
runInstruction (Memory [] ys) Lft = return (return (Memory [] (0:ys)), return ())
runInstruction (Memory xs (y:ys)) Inc = return (return (Memory xs ((y+1):ys)), return ())
runInstruction (Memory xs (y:ys)) Dec = return (return (Memory xs ((y-1):ys)), return ())
runInstruction mem@(Memory _ (x:xs)) Out = return (return mem, putChar (chr x))
runInstruction (Memory xs (y:ys)) Inp = return (mem', return ())
                                          where mem' = getChar >>= \z -> return (Memory xs ((ord z):ys))
runInstruction mem@(Memory xs (0:ys)) (Loop _) = return (return mem, return ())
runInstruction mem (Loop prog) = do
                                    (mem1, act') <- runProgram mem prog
                                    mem' <- mem1
                                    (mem'', act'') <- runInstruction mem' (Loop prog)
                                    return (mem'', act' >> act'')



runProgram :: Memory -> Program -> IO (IO Memory, IO ())
runProgram mem [] = return (return mem, return ())
runProgram mem (i:is) = do
                           (mem1, act1) <- runInstruction mem i
                           mem' <- mem1
                           (mem2, act2) <- runProgram mem' is
                           return (mem2, act1 >> act2)

main :: IO ()
main = do
   hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering 
   (fileName:_) <- getArgs
   prog <- readFile fileName
   (mem, act) <- runProgram emptyMem (parse (filter (`elem` "[]+-><.,") prog))
   act
```

Comment: You can substitute `return (mem2, act1 >> act2)` with `(,) <$> mem2 <*> (act1 >> act2)` to get `IO (Memory, ())`. Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, good job. Now, what can we improve? Let's start with the largest function first, `runInstruction`:

```
runInstruction :: Memory -> Instruction -> IO (IO Memory, IO ())
runInstruction mem Nop = return (return mem, return ())
runInstruction (Memory xs (y:[])) Rgt = return (return (Memory (y:xs) [0]), return ())
runInstruction (Memory xs (y:ys)) Rgt = return (return (Memory (y:xs) ys), return ())
runInstruction (Memory (x:xs) ys) Lft = return (return (Memory xs (x:ys)), return ())
runInstruction (Memory [] ys) Lft = return (return (Memory [] (0:ys)), return ())
runInstruction (Memory xs (y:ys)) Inc = return (return (Memory xs ((y+1):ys)), return ())
runInstruction (Memory xs (y:ys)) Dec = return (return (Memory xs ((y-1):ys)), return ())
runInstruction mem@(Memory _ (x:xs)) Out = return (return mem, putChar (chr x))
runInstruction (Memory xs (y:ys)) Inp = return (mem', return ())
                                          where mem' = getChar >>= \z -> return (Memory xs ((ord z):ys))
runInstruction mem@(Memory xs (0:ys)) (Loop _) = return (return mem, return ())
runInstruction mem (Loop prog) = do
                                    (mem1, act') <- runProgram mem prog
                                    mem' <- mem1
                                    (mem'', act'') <- runInstruction mem' (Loop prog)
                                    return (mem'', act' >> act'')
```

## "Memory" handling

Almost all of those functions concern `Memory`, which isn't obvious. That's because your included all `Memory` functionality into `runInstruction`. If you follow that model, you can never use `Memory` in any other context.

So instead let us write some other functions:

```
moveRight   :: Memory -> Memory
moveLeft    :: Memory -> Memory
getValue    :: Memory -> Int
setValue    :: Int -> Memory -> Int
modifyValue :: (Int -> Int) -> Memory -> Memory
```

Instead of `data Memory = Memory [Int] [Int]`, we're going to use

```
data Memory = Memory [Int] Int [Int]
```

That way we will *always* have a current value. The initial empty memory is the same as yours, except for the pivot value

```
emptyMemory = Memory [] 0 []
```

and moving left or right stays mostly the same:

```
moveRight (Memory []     v rs) = Memory [] 0 (v:rs)
moveRight (Memory (l:ls) v rs) = Memory ls l (v:rs)
moveLeft (Memory ls v [])     = Memory (v:ls) 0 []
moveLeft (Memory ls v (r:rs)) = Memory (v:ls) r rs

getValue (Memory _ v _ )       = v
setValue v                     = modifyValue (const v)
modifyValue f (Memory ls v rs) = Memory ls (f v) rs
```

What's nice about those functions is that we can easily check them with [QuickCheck](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.9.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html) or other testing frameworks, since they are all pure. For example, we can check that

```
prop_set_get x mem = getValue (setValue x mem)   == x
prop_set_set x mem = setValue (setValue x mem)   == (setValue x mem)
prop_get_set   mem = setValue (getValue mem) mem == mem
```

This is hard to check with your current variant.

By the way your variant was completely opaque whether the left or the right list would provide the pivot element. Our new `Memory` makes sure that we cannot do it wrong, and that `v` in `Memory _ v _` always exists.

How does `runInstruction` look with those changes?

```
runInstruction :: Memory -> Instruction -> IO (IO Memory, IO ())
runInstruction mem Nop = return (return mem, return ())
runInstruction mem Rgt = return (return (moveRight mem), return ())
runInstruction mem Lft = return (return (moveLeft  mem), return ())
runInstruction mem Inc = return (return (modifyValue succ mem), return ())
runInstruction mem Dec = return (return (modifyValue pred mem), return ())
runInstruction mem Out = return (return mem, putChar (chr (getValue mem)))
runInstruction mem Inp = return (mem'      , return ())
                           where mem' = getChar >>= \z -> return (setValue (const z) mem)
runInstruction mem (Loop prog)
  | getValue mem == 0 = return (return mem, return ())
  | otherwise         = do
                        (mem1, act') <- runProgram mem prog
                        mem' <- mem1
                        (mem'', act'') <- runInstruction mem' (Loop prog)
                        return (mem'', act' >> act'')
```

Almost readable, right? But something is still off.

## Better types

Your result type of `runInstruction` doesn't really capture what you want to do. You want to *run* an instruction and get a new `Memory`, maybe with some output on your console, or some user input taken. But even without that information, we'll notice that you never user the `IO ()` part of your result, except for `putChar`. That line could also get written as

```
runInstruction mem Out = putChar (getValue mem) >> return (return mem, return ())
```

Therefore we don't need it at all. So we could use `IO (IO Memory)` instead (spoiler: **don't**):

```
runInstruction :: Memory -> Instruction -> IO (IO Memory)
runInstruction mem Nop = return (return mem)
runInstruction mem Rgt = return (return (moveRight mem))
runInstruction mem Lft = return (return (moveLeft  mem))
runInstruction mem Inc = return (return (modifyValue succ mem))
... don't use this!
```

But we're stopping short before the finish line. As I said, you just want to change the memory in your program, and maybe, *maybe* want to show or take some text. So `runInstruction`'s correct type would be:

```
runInstruction :: Instruction -> Memory -> IO Memory
```

It's implementation stays the same, except that we lose several `return`s:

```
runInstruction :: Instruction -> Memory -> IO Memory
runInstruction i mem@(Memory _ v _) = case i of
  Lft       -> return (moveLeft mem)
  Rgt       -> return (moveRight mem)
  Inc       -> return (modifyValue succ mem)
  Dec       -> return (modifyValue pred mem)
  Out       -> putChar v >> return mem
  Inp       -> (\z -> setValue (ord z) mem) `fmap` getChar
  Loop _ | v == 0 -> return mem
  Loop p    -> runProgram p mem >>= runInstruction i
  _         -> return mem
```

I've switched the order of `Memory` and `Instruction` so that both occurences of `Memory` are closer to each other. Of course, this means that we need to change `runProgram` too, but that change isn't really large:

```
runProgram :: Program -> Memory -> IO Memory
runProgram []     mem = return mem
runProgram (i:is) mem = runInstruction i mem >>= runProgram is
```

I think the last lines in both functions showed why I moved `Memory` to be the last argument.

You're off course free to change `runInstruction` back to your pattern matching variant.

## Time for some exercises

Now that we have something that's easier to read, it would be time to refactor. So here are some exercises:

1. Brainfuck only supports integers from 0-255 officially, and it wraps. This should get reflected in our functions. With our new program structure, there is only one single point where you need to change something. Where? And why?
2. Instead of `Nop`, use `Comment Char`. That way, you can still have a look at the code.
3. Try to make a variant of `runProgram` that takes a `String` to simulate user input and produces a `String` to simulate output.
4. Try to parse more variants of Brainfuck, for example [charmander](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/128833/21002), whitespace or Ook?!.