# A simple brainf*** interpreter in Haskell

Tags: beginner, haskell, interpreter, brainfuck

I am very new to Haskell and come from languages like C++, although I do have some experience with Scheme. Here, I wrote a simple brainf*** interpreter, which so far is my largest project. I followed a tutorial for some of the code (such as the `Tape` data type), but did most of this on my own. I have one major concern with my approach, which is the way I handle the loops (which in brainf*** are written with `[]` and repeat until the current cell in the tape is zero. In my implementation, I used the loop as a parameter to the main recursive function, which is called if the current instruction is `]` and the current cell is not `0`. Since these loops modify the tape, I had to make them return an instance of `Tape` that would replace the current one. However, since the function also handles IO (and therefore must return an instance of `IO`), I made it return an `IO (Tape Int)` which is then unpacked in a `do` block. This all felt very messy and hacky, so I would really appreciate any help from more experienced Haskell developers.

```
import Data.Maybe

--The Tape data type and functions

data Tape a = Tape [a] a [a] 

newTape :: a -> Tape a 
newTape x = Tape r x r 
    where r = repeat x

moveLeft :: Tape a -> Tape a 
moveLeft (Tape (l:ls) x rs) = Tape ls l (x:rs)  

moveRight :: Tape a -> Tape a
moveRight (Tape ls x (r:rs)) = Tape (x:ls) r rs 

--The Brainf*** instruction data types

data BfInstruction 
    = MovLeft
    | MovRight
    | Increment
    | Decrement
    | Output
    | Input 
    | BeginLoop
    | EndLoop    
    deriving (Show, Eq)  

type BfProgram = [BfInstruction]

--Convert string to BfProgram

parseBf :: String -> BfProgram
parseBf = mapMaybe parse
    where 
        parse :: Char -> Maybe BfInstruction
        parse x = case x of
            '<' -> Just MovLeft
            '>' -> Just MovRight 
            '+' -> Just Increment
            '-' -> Just Decrement
            ',' -> Just Input
            '.' -> Just Output
            '[' -> Just BeginLoop
            ']' -> Just EndLoop
            x   -> Nothing         --anything but the above chars is a comment

--Main running function

runBf :: String -> IO () 
runBf p = runBf' (parseBf p) (newTape 0) [] >> return ()
    where 
        runBf' :: BfProgram -> Tape Int -> BfProgram -> IO (Tape Int) 
        runBf' [] tape _ = return tape 
        runBf' prog@(p:ps) tape@(Tape ls x rs) loop = case p of
            MovLeft   -> advance prog (moveLeft tape)
            MovRight  -> advance prog (moveRight tape)
            Increment -> advance prog (Tape ls (x+1) rs)
            Decrement -> advance prog (Tape ls (x-1) rs)
            Input     -> do 
                char <- getChar 
                advance prog (Tape ls (fromEnum char) rs)  
            Output    -> putChar (toEnum x) >> advance prog tape 
            BeginLoop -> 
                let lp = getLoop 1 ps
                in runBf' (length lp `drop` ps) tape lp  --Drop so that we are at the ] now
            EndLoop   -> 
                if x /= 0 
                then do 
                    lt <- runBf' loop tape [] 
                    runBf' prog lt loop       --Copy the tape from the result of the loop into next iteration
                else advance prog tape 

        advance :: BfProgram -> Tape Int -> IO (Tape Int) 
        advance (p:ps) tape = runBf' ps tape []  

        getLoop :: Int -> BfProgram -> BfProgram
        getLoop _ [] = error "Mismatched brackets in BF program"
        getLoop 1 (EndLoop:ps) = [] 
        getLoop n (p:ps) = p:case p of 
            BeginLoop -> getLoop (n + 1) ps 
            EndLoop   -> getLoop (n - 1) ps 
            _         -> getLoop n ps

--Simple IO

main = do 
    program <- readFile "program.bf"
    runBf program
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. That almost looks like literate Haskell, did you mean to split your code into several snippets?

Comment: I did? I separated my data type definitions and functions. What should I have done?

Comment: You can keep it like this, but it's usually better if code is kept copyable (e.g. one file = one code block) so that interested reviewers can test your program (it's not a required, though).  [Literate Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Literate_programming) looks very similar to your presentation style, so you might be interested in it.

Comment: Ok thank you. I looked around and saw some other people doing it, so I split mine up too. Just adjusted it.

Comment: It's not required per-se to keep the code together, you can keep the code split for presentation purposes, sorry if my comment made it sound like a requirement. Either way, I hope you get some nice reviews.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well done. Overall, there are no big flaws, just some minor issues.

## Type annotations

While it's great that all top-level functions have proper type signatures, the local bindings *inside* those functions usually don't. After all, their types should get inferred, e.g.

```
example :: [Int] -> [Int]
example = map inc
  where
    inc x = 1 + x
```

doesn't need a type signature since `x`'s type is already fixed to `Int`. It makes refactoring also a lot easier if we change the type later. If we started with

```
example :: [Int] -> [Int]
example = map inc
  where
    inc :: Int -> Int
    inc x = 1 + x
```

and later want to generalize, we might forget the second type signature and end up with an error message:

```
example :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
example = map inc
  where
    inc :: Int -> Int -- whoops, GHC will yell about that
    inc x = 1 + x
```

Therefore, type signatures for local functions are usually not written out. There are some instances where they're necessary, but that's usually with `RankNTypes` or other extensions.

## The tape

The tape works well, and is pretty much how you would expect it.

### Infinite tapes and debugging

That being said, an infinite tape has the slight inconvenience that you can never inspect it for debugging purposes.

Also, if you ever create a module from your code, you must not export the `Tape` data constructor, as it would enable `Tape [] 0 []` and therefore break assertions.

A finite tape circumvents those issues, but needs slightly more effort in the `move`ments.

### Working on the current value

In `runBf` we can find several spots where we `advance` the program after we worked on the current value, e.g.:

```
        Increment -> advance prog (Tape ls (x+1) rs)
        Decrement -> advance prog (Tape ls (x-1) rs)
```

That's now a possible source of errors, since we could have used

```
        Increment -> advance prog (Tape ls (x+1) ls)
        Decrement -> advance prog (Tape ls (x-1) ls)
```

by accident. A small helper can prevent that issue:

```
onCurrent :: (a -> a) -> Tape a -> Tape a
onCurrent f (Tape ls x rs) = Tape ls (f x) rs

current   :: Tape a -> a
current (Tape _ x _ ) = x
```

Then we end up with

```
        MovLeft   -> advance prog (moveLeft tape)
        MovRight  -> advance prog (moveRight tape)
        Increment -> advance prog (onCurrent (+1) tape)
        Decrement -> advance prog (onCurrent (subtract 1) tape)
        Input     -> do 
            char <- getChar 
            advance prog (onCurrent (const (fromEnum char)) tape)
```

## Naming and scope

As neither `advance` nor `getLoop` use any of the bindings in their scope, they're candidates for top-level functions.

`runBf'` can be called `go` or another short name. Calling the inner worker just `go` is really common and won't alienate other readers.

## Make interfaces hard to use wrong

`getLoop` uses an `Int` as first argument that's not properly documented. Types only go so far as documentation, and we could accidentally use `getLoop 0` in `BeginLoop`.

Instead, we should make it impossible to misuse `getLoop`:

```
getLoop :: BfProgram -> BfProgram
getLoop = go 1
  where
    go _ [] = error "Mismatched brackets in BF program"
    go 1 (EndLoop:ps) = [] 
    go n (p:ps) = p:case p of 
        BeginLoop -> go (n + 1) ps 
        EndLoop   -> go (n - 1) ps 
        _         -> go n ps
```

Similarly, `runBf` should probably take a `BfProgram`, not an arbitrary `String`, as this doesn't decrease the strength of your program, we can recreate the previous behaviour with

```
runBf . parseBf
```

However, speaking of parsing…

## Loop validation

A drawback with our current `BfProgram` is that we might end up with mismatched brackets, e.g.

```
parseBf "]["
```

parses fine and leads to a runtime error. However, we could easily detect that during parsing. Our `parseBf` needs a way to report errors:

```
type ParserError = String

parseBf :: String -> Either ParserError BfProgram
parseBf = go
  where 
    go []     = Right []
    go (x:xs) = case x of
        '<' -> MovLeft <$:> go xs
        '>' -> MovRight <$:> go xs
        '+' -> Increment <$:> go xs
        '-' -> Decrement <$:> go xs
        ',' -> Input <$:> go xs
        '.' -> Output <$:> go xs
        '[' -> -- exercise ; use `getLoop`-like function
        ']' -> -- exercise ; easier if previous one done correctly.
        x   -> go xs
   x <$:> xs = fmap (x:) xs
```

but afterwards, we can be sure that `parseBf` only returns `BfProgram`s with valid brackets.

Unfortunately, we still need to use `getLoop`, as `BeginLoop` and `EndLoop` are still in our instruction set. If we change the instruction set, we can get rid of that too:

```
data BfInstruction 
    = MovLeft
    | MovRight
    | Increment
    | Decrement
    | Output
    | Input 
    | Loop BfProgram
    deriving (Show, Eq)
```

I go into more details in some of my [previous Bf reviews](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/174330/haskell-brainfck-interpreter-runtime-error-handling/174341#174341), feel free to [read them](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/128833/charmander-brainfuck-interpreter-in-haskell/128841#128841) if you get stuck on `Loop`.

## Final remarks

Other than the usual re-evaluation of loops (which is a common scenario in Haskell Bf interpreters), your code was fine, so all the issues are really minor. Again: well done.